# What is included in GC.GetTotalMemory() that I can't control?

Tags: c#, .net, memory

This "must be" a dumb question but I've spent 3 days looking for an answer and can't find it, so here goes.

I have a simple c# app (.NET 5) with 1 form, and I'm running one method that reads a bunch of data from disk (about 1 GB), processes it, and dumps the results (about 1 GB) back to disk. I'm trying to do memory profiling to make sure my memory management is reasonably efficient.

Using the .NET Memory Profiler gives me what I expect... my app starts with a 4 MB footprint, and after cleaning up and forcing garbage collection it ends up at about 10 MB managed memory which makes sense relative to the few small objects I have left over. But `GC.TotalMemory()` only gets down to about 110 MB, which is consistent with what I see in Windows Task Manager and what I get from `Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64` and `Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64`. Most of that 110 MB is accumulated while the app is writing files to disk. Some is accumulated while processing the data, and essentially none is accumulated while reading from disk.

My question is, does `GC.GetTotalMemory()` include a bunch of .NET overhead that I can't control and the garbage collector can't collect, or do I still have cleanup work to do in my own code? If it's the latter then I'm not sure where to start since everything looks fine with .NET Memory Profiler. If it's the former then my follow-up question is: I knew .NET was a resource hog, but is it really that bad?

I'm doing multiple calls to `GC.Collect()` in my debugging code.

Comment: Can you post the save code and some profiler screenshots? Also I have not used 'memory profiler' before, but give the microsoft 'CLR profiler' a try. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLR_Profiler Google it too and make sure you view the memory use graphic visualization (I forget the name of the diagram but it's cool - and useful). This has gotten me out of similar situations. And at the end of the day if you have a 6+ gig machine... No way is 100 Meg worth your time, just restart the app :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving the original question open since I would really like to know the answer, but I resolved my immediate issue with memory profiling my current project.

The problem was with System.Threading.Timers hanging around in the classes used for processing and writing data. The timers were stopped and irrelevant for the method I'm debugging, but evidently they still have the potential to cause issues with (1) preventing memory from being released to the GC, no matter how hard you try, and (2) the .NET Memory Profiler reporting. Disposing and/or nulling the timers didn't impress the GC at all, in the end I had to just split them off from the classes where all the memory requirements reside. After this everything works as expected, the .NET Memory Profiler reports make perfect sense and it was easy to debug a couple of memory issues and move on.